# STATCKED on trigger updateing same row in same table depend on other column value

Tags: mysql

this is the trigger

this is the table Stracture:

```
id:               int
item_counting:    int
item_disterbute:  int
item_stor:        int
```

now in case of update only:

```
BEGIN
        IF item_counting = NEW.item_disterbute THEN
            SET NEW.item_stor = 2;

        ELSEIF item_counting > NEW.item_disterbute THEN
            SET NEW.item_stor = 3;

        ELSE
            SET NEW.item_stor = 4;

        END IF;
    END
```

Now how i can keep the column of **item_counting**

here it's giving error on update:    `1054 - Unknown column 'item_counting' in 'field list'`

Comment: it should be `if old.item_counting` and so on

Comment: That's is corrent the solution is solved

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty please post ur comment on answer so i mark it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the keyword `old` or `new` to get the column value depending on the trigger.

Say if you are running a `before update` trigger then using `old.column_name` would give you the value currently its having and `new.column_name` is the value being supplied for the update, you can set your own.

So in your case it would be

```
    IF old.item_counting = NEW.item_disterbute THEN
        SET NEW.item_stor = 2;

    ELSEIF old.item_counting > NEW.item_disterbute THEN
        SET NEW.item_stor = 3;

    ELSE
        SET NEW.item_stor = 4;

    END IF;
```